# Flask + Ajax Integration : AttributeError: 'WSGIRequestHandler' object has no attribute 'environ'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, python-2.7, flask

So I am trying to use ajax to execute a python file which basically continuously checks if a text file contents are changing and if so, it will return to the ajax where it will do the appropriate action. The python scripts needs to begin as the page loads.

This is my python file:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/") 
def checkFile():
    filename = "demo.txt"
while True:
    file = open(filename)
    for line in file:
        value = line
        intValue = int(value)
        if intValue < 50:
            return "done"
        else:
            continue

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', debug=True, port=5000)
```

This is my JS file ( inside ready() ):

```
            $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url: "https://localhost:5000",
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log("Response-Success: " + data);
                    if(data == "done") {
                        console.log("DONE!!!");
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("NOPE!!!");
                    }
                },
                error:function(data) {
                    console.log("Response-Error: " + data);
                }
            }).done(function(data) {
                console.log("Response-Done: " + data);
            });
```

The error that I am getting is: (This is when the request to the python script takes place, this is shown in the python server console) :

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 52078)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
self.process_request(request, client_address)
File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
self.finish_request(request, client_address)
File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
File "C:\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 655, in __init__
self.handle()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug-0.11.4-    py2.7.egg\werkzeug\serving .py", line 216, in handle
rv = BaseHTTPRequestHandler.handle(self)
File "C:\Python27\lib\BaseHTTPServer.py", line 340, in handle
self.handle_one_request()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug-0.11.4- py2.7.egg\werkzeug\serving.py", line 250, in handle_one_request
elif self.parse_request():
File "C:\Python27\lib\BaseHTTPServer.py", line 253, in parse_request
self.send_error(400, "Bad request version (%r)" % version)
File "C:\Python27\lib\BaseHTTPServer.py", line 364, in send_error
self.log_error("code %d, message %s", code, message)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug-0.11.4-py2.7.egg\werkzeug\serving.py", line 272, in log_error
self.log('error', *args)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug-0.11.4-py2.7.egg\werkzeug\serving.py", line 278, in log
_log(type, '%s - - [%s] %s\n' % (self.address_string(),
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug-0.11.4-py2.7.egg\werkzeug\serving.py", line 266, in address_string
return self.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']
AttributeError: 'WSGIRequestHandler' object has no attribute 'environ'
```

Could you please tell me what to do in this situation?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the error may be arising because of the use of 'https' in your javascript file.

```
url: "https://localhost:5000"
```

I am assuming that you are running Flask locally here and that it is configured only to handle http.